# call javascript function in asp.net through a form using master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Asp.net and designing a web site.
I have a master form with header,navigation bar,sidebar,footer which is common for every web page and a content area which differs for every page.
I am creating the web pages using master page and adding controls on content area.
but the problem is i am using javascript in the web page and want to call a method onload function of the web page.

This is the sample code:

```
    var a = ["..images/airline.jpg","..images/c1.jpg","..images/3.jpg"];
    var i = 0;
    function imageforward() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById("myimage").src = a[i];

        if (i == 3) {
            i = -1;
        }

    }
    function TimeStart() {

        setInterval(imageforward, 8000);

    }
```

How to call the method. Please help me to do so.
Thank you..

Comment: which method you want to call on load?

Comment: timestart(); I have wriiten the methods in script tag of master form and want to call them in the child form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DOMContentLoaded` eventListener

```
document.addEvenetListner(timestart,false);
```

OR Simply:

```
 window.onload=timestart;
```

Comment: where to add the code: window.onload=FUNCTION_NAME; I need this function for just one page.

Comment: in your page's `<head><script>`

Comment: I am not able to add the <head> in the content area.

Comment: then simply add in anywhere in the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

After you define TimeStart function just call it like that :

```
TimeStart();
```

If you use jQuery you can put it on document ready like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   TimeStart();
})
```

If no jQuery is present you can use :

```
window.onload = TimeStart;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the neccassary javscript libraries to your masterpage. (Jquery)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Scripts/jquery-version.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Scripts/additional-js.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Alternativly you can just reference it in the `<head>` part of the master file

```
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-version.js") %>' type="text/javascript></script>
```

After this call your function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        TimeStart();
        //additional code
});
```